# Calling my plugin in buildsrc/ several times

Tags: gradle, gradle-plugin

I had a monolythic `build.gradle` to build one application. It's composed of several tasks (minify, combine files, gzip, upload to CDN, calling external scripts, etc etc)

I managed to move everything in `build.gradle` to a custom plugin in `buildsrc/`, following official Gradle tutorial of GreetingPlugin in the docs. After some effort, I can successfully call it now from `build.gradle` amd it works as expected:

```
group 'CDN'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

buildscript {
    .
    .
}

println "building user app"
apply plugin: BuildAppModule
appmodulebuilder.modulename = 'user'
```

So far so good. But my purpose of moving everything to a plugin in buildsrc/ was to be able to call this plugin several times to build the different modules.

Naively, I tried this:

```
.
.
println "building user app"
apply plugin: BuildAppModule
appmodulebuilder.modulename = 'user'

println "building admin app"
apply plugin: BuildAppModule
appmodulebuilder.modulename = 'admin'
```

and this

```
task buildUser {
    println "building user app"
    apply plugin: BuildAppModule
    appmodulebuilder.modulename = 'user'
}
task buildAdmin {
    println "building admin app"
    apply plugin: BuildAppModule
    appmodulebuilder.modulename = 'admin'
}
```

and this

```
task buildUser {
    doLast {
        println "building user app"
        apply plugin: BuildAppModule
        appmodulebuilder.modulename = 'user'
    }
}
task buildAdmin {
    doLast {
        println "building admin app"
        apply plugin: BuildAppModule
        appmodulebuilder.modulename = 'admin'
    }
}
```

and this

```
  apply plugin: BuildAppModule
  task buildUser (Type: BuildAppModule) {
        doLast {
            println "building user app"
            appmodulebuilder.modulename = 'user'
        }
    }
    task buildAdmin (Type: BuildAppModule) {
        doLast {
            println "building admin app"
            appmodulebuilder.modulename = 'admin'
        }
    }
```

However the plugin is never executed 2 times. The closest I've been, the plugin is executed one time with the last provided value.

Can anybody please help me without a "read the plugin section of gradle documentation" - kind of answer? (that I have, but found it very unapproachable for gradle newcomers!)

---

EDIT: The whole plugin, my needs are to execute this over a set of directories.

**buildSrc/main/groovy/BuildAppModule.groovy**

```
import org.gradle.api.Plugin;
import org.gradle.api.Project;
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.Configuration;
import org.gradle.api.artifacts.ProjectDependency;
import org.gradle.api.tasks.Exec;

class BuildAppModuleExtension {
    String modulename
}

class  BuildAppModule implements Plugin<Project> {


    void apply(Project project) {

        def extension = project.extensions.create('appmodulebuilder', BuildAppModuleExtension)

        project.afterEvaluate {
            println "-----------------------------"
            println extension.modulename
            println "-----------------------------"
        }

        def APP = extension.modulename
        def buildDir = project.getBuildDir()

        project.configure(project) {

            apply plugin: 'js'
            javascript.source {
                /** common libraries */
                lib {
                    js {
                        srcDir 'src/lib'
                        include "*.js"
                    }
                }

                /** specific app files */
                appfiles {
                    js {
                        srcDir "src/app/${APP}"
                        include "*.js"
                    }
                }

                closurein {
                    js {
                        srcDir 'src/lib/closure'
                        include "in.jst"
                    }
                }
                closureout {
                    js {
                        srcDir 'src/lib/closure'
                        include "out.jst"
                    }
                }
            }

            // Configure the built-in task
            combineJs {
                source = [ javascript.source.closurein.js.files, javascript.source.lib.js.files, javascript.source.appfiles.js.files, javascript.source.closureout.js.files ]
                dest = file("${buildDir}/${APP}/js/code.debug.js")
            }


            minifyJs {
                source = combineJs
                dest = file("${buildDir}/${APP}/js/code.min.js")
                sourceMap = file("${buildDir}/${APP}/js/code.sourcemap.json")
                closure {
                    warningLevel = 'QUIET'
                }
                dependsOn 'undebug'
            }

            gzipJs {
                source=file("${buildDir}/${APP}/js/code.min.js")
                dest = file("${buildDir}/out/app/lib-${APP}/code.js")
            }

            apply plugin: 'css'
            css.source {
                lib {
                    css {
                        srcDir 'src/res'
                        include "*.css"
                    }
                }
                appfiles {
                    css {
                        srcDir "src/app/${APP}/res"
                        include "*.css"
                    }
                }
            }

            // Specify a collection of files to be combined, then minified and finally GZip compressed.

            combineCss {
                source =  [css.source.lib.css.files, css.source.appfiles.css.files]
                dest = "${buildDir}/${APP}/res/style.all.css"
            }

            minifyCss {
                source = combineCss
                dest = "${buildDir}/${APP}/res/style.min.css"
                yuicompressor { // Optional
                    lineBreakPos = -1
                }
            }

            gzipCss {
                dependsOn 'minifyCss'
                source = minifyCss
                dest = "${buildDir}/out/app/lib-${APP}/style.css"
            }

        }
        project.task('gzipHtml') {

           doLast {

               def uploadOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

               getProject().exec {

                   println "$buildDir"
                   commandLine "scripts/dohtml.sh","src/app","$buildDir/out/app", "$APP"
                   standardOutput = uploadOut

               }

               println uploadOut
           }
        }

        /** upload module to the CDN, the final step */
        project.task('upload') {


            dependsOn 'gzipJs'
            dependsOn 'gzipHtml'

            doLast {

                println "UPLOAD $APP"
                def uploadOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

                getProject().exec {

                    println "$buildDir"
                    commandLine "scripts/upload.sh","$buildDir/out/app/","s3://xxxxxxx/public/app/"
                    standardOutput = uploadOut

                }

                println uploadOut

            }

            /** remove window.console.log from the combined JS file */
            project.task('undebug') {

                dependsOn 'combineJs'

                doLast {

                    def uploadOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream()

                    getProject().exec {

                        println "UNDEBUG $APP"
                        commandLine "scripts/undebug.sh","${buildDir}/${APP}/js/code.debug.js"
                        standardOutput = uploadOut

                    }

                    println uploadOut
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A plugin can only be applied once to a project. Any attempts to apply the same plugin a second or subsequent time will have no effect.

I get the feeling that your plugin should add an [extension object](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:getting_input_from_the_build) which can be configured after applying the plugin.

Eg:

```
apply plugin: BuildAppModule
appModuleBuilder {
    moduleNames = ['user', 'admin']        
}
```

Or perhaps

```
apply plugin: BuildAppModule
appModuleBuilder {
    module {
        name = 'user'
        type = 'xxx'
    }
    module {
        name = 'admin'
        type = 'yyy'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Lance for giving me a concise answer impossible to find online. So it means I have to rework my plugin to somehow build the subprojects in a loop? Or should I do different build.gradles in the different modules subdirs?

Comment: It's hard to know exactly what you're up to. Perhaps you just want implement a [Task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Task.html) which can be added multiple times in a `build.gradle`. If that's the case you don't need a plugin... hard to know without more info

Comment: Please note that you should never do any "work" outside of a task. Ultimately, your plugin will be adding tasks to the project and will "wire" the tasks into Gradle's [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). You should NEVER do any "work" in the configuration phase (eg don't do any "work" in Plugin.apply(Project))

Comment: I posted the whole plugin, it's actually pretty simple, my needs are to just execute this over and over again inside the different folders (sub-webapps). Can you please take a look and give me an advice or two? thanks! pd- I guess I'm doing it all wrong based on your advices

Comment: I think you have two options. 1. Have a separate gradle project per "module" and apply the plugin to each gradle project. 2. Add a set of tasks to a single project per "module" and prefix every task name with the module (eg adminMinifyGs, adminCombineJs etc)

Comment: You might be interested in [this code](https://github.com/uklance/gradle-java-flavours/blob/master/src/main/groovy/com/lazan/javaflavours/JavaFlavoursExtension.groovy) where I add tasks per "flavour" and prefix the task names with the flavour. It's a bit similar

Comment: Thanks a lot! definitely helps to see something related that works.